# how Web caching can reduce the delay in receiving a requested object?

Tags: caching, browser-cache

I wonder how Web caching can reduce the delay in receiving a requested object and reduce the delay for all objects requested by a user or for only some of the objects?

Comment: Lets say, you have 100 notes from different users. Me as a user i request to give me my own 10 notes from 100 notes. You search into 100 notes and bring me 10 notes(while you give me the notes you store those 10 notes in cache).Its take 5 second to search in 100 notes. Next time when i request you to give my those 10 notes again, first you search in cached notes. Now it's take less time to find my notes because there are only 10 notes in cache. You return my notes from cache in ~0 second. I think thats how its work. I might wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.